# QGIS, how to create a grid that does not exceed the extent, constrained within the extent

Tags: qgis, extents, grids-graticules

I have to create a grid of 15mx15m over an area much bigger, 25000mx25000m. Of course it means that the grid will never properly fit within the extent, but it will exceed a bit (25000/15=1666.6667). I tried with both the "research tool, vector grid" and the "create grid tool" with MMQGIS. The first create a grid that is bigger than the given extent, the second smaller.

The question has somehow already been asked, but solved poorely with the clip tool... In this case it will take ages by using this tool... Anybody with a better idea?

Answer (score 3):

To create a grid of lines:

```py
# grid properties
left = 0  # left/west of area
bottom = 0  # bottom/south of area
width = 50  # width of area
height = 50  # height of area
x_min = 2  # left most vertical line
y_min = 2  # lower most horizontal line
x_spacing=15  # spacing between vertical lines
y_spacing=15  # spacing between horizonatl lines

# target layer
gridlines = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=epsg:4326', 'gridlines', 'memory')
prov = gridlines.dataProvider()

# feature list
feats = []

# boundary
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(bottom, left), QgsPoint(bottom, height),
    QgsPoint(width, height), QgsPoint(width, left),
    QgsPoint(bottom, left)]))
feats.append(feat)

# vertical grid lines
for pos in range(x_min, width, x_spacing):
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(pos, left), QgsPoint(pos, height)]))
    feats.append(feat)

# horizontal grid lines
for pos in range(y_min, height, y_spacing):
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(bottom, pos), QgsPoint(width, pos)]))
    feats.append(feat)

# add the new feature
result = prov.addFeatures(feats)
if result:
    gridlines.updateExtents()
    gridlines.triggerRepaint()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(gridlines)
```

Afterwards you can convert the lines to polygons, or elaborate the code. With the above settings you receive this:

[image: gridlines]